# Android: How to passing XML file to .net WebService and progress the XML file in Web Service?

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, web-services, dom, xml-parsing

I would like to create and pass a Xml file to .net Web services by using the following code. However, i don't know how to get and progress this XML file in .net Web Services. Can you help me to solve this problem please ?

```
public void registration(String[] data) {       

 String line = "<UserData
                Name=\"Username" Email = \"emaiAddress" Password = \"Password" +
                "SecurityQuestion = \"Question" SAnswer = \"SAnswer"/>";

 try {

  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(localhost + "UserData");

      StringEntity se = new StringEntity(line, HTTP.UTF_8);

      se.setContentType("text/xml");

  httpPost.setEntity(se);

  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();             

      line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {            

  }
}
```

May i know how to get the attribute from this xml in web services. I try to use the following code. But stuck and don't know how to proceed.

```
//user registration

[WebMethod]
public void registration(XmlDocument data)
{
     XmlDocument xml = data;
     var username = xml.GetElementsByTagName("Username");            



}
```

Thank you in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.,

```
public void registration(String[] data) {       

     String line = "<UserData
                    Name=\"Username" Email = \"emaiAddress" Password = \"Password" +
                    "SecurityQuestion = \"Question" SAnswer = \"SAnswer"/>";

     try {

      DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(localhost + "UserData");

          StringEntity se = new StringEntity(line, HTTP.UTF_8);

          se.setContentType("text/xml");

      httpPost.setEntity(se);

      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
      HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();     

      if (httpResponse != null) {       
                    InputStream in = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = builder.parse(in);

                    if (doc != null) {

                        NodeList Username_node = doc.getElementsByTagName("Username");
                        String usrname = Username_node.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                        System.out.println(""+usrname);
                    }
                } else {
                    showAlert(thisActivity, "No response");
                }

      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {            

      }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, i would like to read the xml file in .net web service and not in android http post. Can you help me on this ?